# Protocol conformance is not inferred for an Element of the Collection

Tags: arrays, swift, collections, protocols, protocol-oriented

I have a set of protocols to be able to display an element in an *UITableView*:

```
protocol TableRepresentableRow {
  var title: String { get }
  var subtitle: String { get }
}

extension TableRepresentableRow {
  var title: String {return ""}
  var subtitle: String {return ""}
}

protocol TableRepresentableSection {
  var title: String { get }
  var count: Int { get }
  subscript(index: Int) -> TableRepresentableRow {get}
}

extension TableRepresentableSection {
  var title: String {
    return ""
  }
}
```

An individual element conforms to the *TableRepresentableRow* protocol:

```
extension ServicesSummary.Service: TableRepresentableRow {
  var title: String {
    return serviceNumber
  }
  var subtitle: String {
    return serviceUserName
  }
}
```

I expect the protocol conformance to be inferred in the *TableRepresentableSection* too, since *ServicesSummary.Service* is *TableRepresentableRow* however, this doesn't happen:

```
extension Array: TableRepresentableSection where Element == ServicesSummary.Service {
  // Error: the compiler requires me to add subscript too, while it should be inferred
  subscript(index: Int) -> TableRepresentableRow {
    <#code#>
  }

  var title: String {
    return first?.businessType.rawValue.uppercased() ?? ""
  }
}
```

Why do I get this error?

**Update:** 
Protocol composition doesn't work also:
[image]

Comment: See my updated answer, if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, change the Element type check to protocol only:

Change:

```
where Element == ServicesSummary.Service
```

to:

```
where Element == TableRepresentableRow
```

Whole extension:

```
extension Array: TableRepresentableSection where Element == TableRepresentableRow {
    var title: String {
        return first?.businessType.rawValue.uppercased() ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: That might work, the only problem is that `businessType` is a part of domain logic. The idea is to provide an extension for the type to be displayed by the `TableView`.

Comment: You can still cast your Element to your wanted Type using `if let` if that was the issue?

Comment: That wouldn't work since I was thinking of creating multiple extensions for different data types, so each of them could be `TableRepresentableRow ` and `TableRepresentableSection` would be inferred (only title would be required).

Answer (score 0):

The `Array` extension only contains the `Array` subscript function that returns an object of type `Element` - in this case `ServicesSummary.Service`. So the subscript function that the compiler requires you to implement is the one from the `TableRepresentableSection` protocol, since this one has a different return type: `TableRepresentableRow`. You have 2 options:

- change type of `Element` to `TableRepresentableRow`
- delete subscript function from `TableRepresentableSection`

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler infer that `ServicesSummary.Service` is `TableRepresentableRow`?

Comment: It does. But the subscript method of `Array` cannot work as the implementation of the method declared in the protocol `TableRepresentableSection`, because they have different return types. All objects of type `ServicesSummary.Service` are considered to conform to type `TableRepresentableRow`, but not all objects that conform to `TableRepresentableRow` are of type `ServicesSummary.Service`. Since the subscript method of `Array` returns an object of type `ServicesSummary.Service`, it cannot be an implementation of a protocol method that returns the more generic type `TableRepresentableRow`.

Answer (score 0):

I finished with the following code, removing `subscript` from the protocol completely:

```
protocol TableRepresentableRow {
  var title: String { get }
  var subtitle: String { get }
}

extension TableRepresentableRow {
  var title: String {return ""}
  var subtitle: String {return ""}
}

protocol TableRepresentableSection {
  var title: String { get }
  var items: [TableRepresentableRow] { get }
}

extension TableRepresentableSection {
  var title: String {
    return ""
  }
}
```